# The gradient of multiplication of matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, python

In the following snippet of Python code using [`@`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465) and [`GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape), I cannot understand how the `x` vector of shape `(3,1)` and the `w` vector of shape `(1,2)` produce `[6.,6.]`. Can anyone please explain it to me?

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1.], [2.], [3.]])    #shape=(3, 1)
w = tf.Variable(tf.ones((1, 2)))       #shape=(1, 2)
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones((3,2)))

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    y = x @ w + b 

dy_dw = tape.gradient(y,w) 
print(dy_dw)
```

Comment: This amounts to differentiating a 3-by-2 matrix with respect to a 2-vector. That can be done, but there's not a universal convention for it. So the answer is probably buried somewhere in the linked documentation.

Comment: Are you sure of the 2-by-1 dimension of dy_dw ? If you vectorize things, it should be a 6-by-2 matrix (whose sum along rows give |6,6] by the way )